# How to make a batch-file loop that saves the content of an array to a file

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I'm in need of a piece of Windows batch code that prints the contents of an arbitrary length starting from index 0 from array to a file with each value going to a new line in the file.

This is the code i tried to use for it:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
:saveloop
if not defined !array%i%! goto endsaveloop
echo !array%i%! >> examplefile.txt
set/a i+=1
goto saveloop
:endsaveloop
```

So I expect it to create file called `examplefile.txt` consisting of the content of the array `!array%i%!`, for example if the content of the array was 
`exampledata1` and `exampledata2`,
 the file should contain

```
exampledata1
exampledata2
```

but during execution it just jumps the first time through the loop at 
`if not defined !array%i%! goto endsaveloop`
even though `!array%i%!` is definitely defined at that point.

Comment: it's `if defined var`, not `if defined %var%` so your code should read: `if not defined array%i% goto endsaveloop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find

```
set array>examplefile
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set array 2^>nul') >>examplefile
```

useful.

`set array` displays the *current* (ie. runtime) values of all variablenames that start `array`.

The format of the first should be

```
array1=37
array10=61
array11=89
array2=55
...
```

so you can easily reload the array exactly as it was with

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type examplefile') do set "%%a"
```

The second should just yield

```
37
61
89
55
```

Note that this is in strict *alphabetical* order of the variablenames.

As for your problem, you need `if not defined array%i%` as `!array%i%!` is the *contents* of the variable whereas without the `!` it is the variable itself. You would for instance be executing `if (not) defined 4` if the contents of the variablename `array%i%` was `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I usuallly use `Set` to iterate through arrays as long as I pad with 0s if the sequence is important